# Route templating with duplicate controller names in different namespaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm implementing something where I want to have a web api sitting beside a more traditional MVC implementation.

The structure looks like:

```
+ Controllers
  + Web
    - Product.cs
  + Api
    - Product.cs
```

In my code, I want to route all requests that come in via `/api` to the `Api` namespace, and everything else to the `Web` namespace, something like:

```
// Want to indicate that these should all choose the the Api namespace
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "api_route",
    template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

// Indicate that these should all choose the from the Web namespace.
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default_route",
    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
```

As far as I can see there is no idiomatic way of indicating which namespace to choose from. Is there a better way to do this? Or do I need to manually specify the route on a per controller basis?

EDIT:
As it goes it seems like this may be a moot point if using Razor views. Regardless, I'll leave this up to see if anyone has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With Owin/Katana on may use `app.Map` to isolate the request pipeline.
I use these two startup configurations to handle these scenarios:

1) Host WebApi at `/api` using a Owin Startup file.

```
app.Map("/api", builder =>
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    builder.UseWebApi(config);
});
```

2) Omit `/api` from the route collection in MVC (set at startup time in Global.asax)

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home",action = "Index",id = UrlParameter.Optional });

// Explicitly tell this route to be solely handled by the Owin pipeline.
RouteTable.Routes.MapOwinPath("/api");
```